# Regex pattern with quotation marks fails

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am a bit puzzled with the failure of this search:

```
epwnymia_string = ' «Β. ΚΙΟΜΟΥΡΤΖΙΔΗΣ – Χ. ΚΙΟΜΟΥΡΤΖΙΔΗΣ ΟΕ» Ο ΠΡΟΕΔΡΟΣ Την 25/9/2013 καταχωρήθηκε με ΚΑΚ 100862 στο Γε'
epwnymia_pattern = re.compile(r'«[^«»]»')
epwnymia_pattern.search(epwnymia_string) # fails to match Β. ΚΙΟΜΟΥΡΤΖΙΔΗΣ – Χ. ΚΙΟΜΟΥΡΤΖΙΔΗΣ ΟΕ
```

What causes the failure and how should I correct my code?

Comment: I think it should be `«[^«»]+»` to select more than one char inside « ... »

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Five regex questions in the same day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do either + or * to get all the characters in-between « » and put the [^«»]* part in brackets so you will be able to get the inner value.

```
import re

epwnymia_string = ' «Β. ΚΙΟΜΟΥΡΤΖΙΔΗΣ – Χ. ΚΙΟΜΟΥΡΤΖΙΔΗΣ ΟΕ» Ο ΠΡΟΕΔΡΟΣ Την 25/9/2013 καταχωρήθηκε με ΚΑΚ 100862 στο Γε'
epwnymia_pattern = re.compile(r'«([^«»]*)»')
print(epwnymia_pattern.search(epwnymia_string).group(1))
```

Output

```
Β. ΚΙΟΜΟΥΡΤΖΙΔΗΣ – Χ. ΚΙΟΜΟΥΡΤΖΙΔΗΣ ΟΕ
```